# Unit Testing hive abstraction layer

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, flutter-hive

So I created a simpler level of abstraction to use Hive into my Flutter app. This should be the central point, where all hive boxes are administrated and accessed. Since e.g. `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` is not available during testing, how can I still manage to test this whole file?

```
import '../services/workout.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_rovider;

import 'workout.dart';

class HiveService {
  static final HiveService _singleton = HiveService._internal();

  static const String _workoutBox = "workoutBox";

  factory HiveService() {
    return _singleton;
  }
  HiveService._internal();

  static Future<void> init() async {
    final appDocumentDirectory =
        await path_rovider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
    Hive.registerAdapter(WorkoutAdapter());
  }

  static Future openWorkouts() {
    return Hive.openBox<Workout>(_workoutBox);
  }

  static Future close() {
    return Hive.close();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First thing first, you need to initial Hive at the top of the `main` method in your test file, and then you can proceed with the rest of the tests.

You can use it in this way:

```
void initHive() {
  var path = Directory.current.path;
  Hive.init(path + '/test/hive_testing_path');
}

main() {
  initHive();
//The rest of your test code.
}
```